# How do I add a "last" class on the last <li> within a Views-generated list?

Tags: css, drupal

How do I add  a "last" class on the last `<li>` within a Views-generated list?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Drupal, care to share code?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use the **last-child** pseudo-class on the li element to achieve this

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
ul li:last-child
{
font-weight:bold
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<ul>
<li>IE</li>
<li>Firefox</li>
<li>Safari</li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

There is also a first-child pseudo class available.

I am not sure the last-child element works in IE though.

Comment: *smacks head* 

Thanks, man - I had forgotten about the CSS pseudoclasses.

Comment: `last-child` supported since IE9

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, you could achieve this via JavaScript if certain browsers don't support the last-child class. For example, this script sets the class name for the last 'li' element in all 'ul' tags, although it could easily be adapted for other tags, or specific elements.

```
function highlightLastLI()
{
    var liList, ulTag, liTag;
    var ulList = document.getElementsByTagName("ul");
    for (var i = 0; i < ulList.length; i++)
    {
        ulTag = ulList[i];
        liList = ulTag.getElementsByTagName("li");
        liTag = liList[liList.length - 1];
        liTag.className = "lastchild";
    }
}
```

Comment: eeek if ever there was a case for using jquery or similar - 12 lines into 1!!

Answer (score 0):

Does jquery come bundled with drupal, if so you could use

```
$('ul>li:last').addClass('last');
```

to achieve this

Answer (score 0):

You can use that pesudo-class **last-child**, **first-child** for first or **nth-child** for any number of child

```
li:last-child{
    color:red;
    font-weight:bold;
}
```